# What does this strange C++ syntax mean?

Tags: c++

This syntax is so strange, I don't know how to understand it.

I don’t know what it means, and I tried searching on major search engines, but the keywords were clueless and no results were found.

Please help me, thanks.

```cpp
auto parser::error(const std::string& msg) -> void
{
    std::cerr << msg << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: It is a [trailing return](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Function_declaration).

Comment: This should be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/2079303

Answer (score 2):

This is C++ 11, with auto type deduction syntax for function return type.
The trailing part **-> void** is called as **trailing return type** syntax

I will refer you to **Effective Modern C++** by Scott Meyers.
This syntax is detailed in Item-3 "Understand decltype" of this book, so just reading the first-3 items will make this syntax clear to you.

This particular case does not seem to be a good use case for this syntax, and it can simply be written as below

```
void parser::error(const std::string& msg)
{
    std::cerr << msg << std::endl;
}
```